# Extract values from array without using OPENJSON because compatibility

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to parse JSON data from SQL with a SQL server that has a compatibility set at 100, so OPENJSON is not an option to use since it requires 130+ and I can't get it changed at the moment.

For now, I am parsing the data that I need using JSON_VALUE in sql.

```
    SELECT   
             JSON_VALUE(Fields, '$.Entry.AnswersJson.page1.Date') AS dump_date,
             JSON_VALUE(Fields, '$.Entry.AnswersJson.page1.Name') AS Name
    FROM Json_Table
```

It works for the first layer of data. But if there is multiple values in a array, it does not return each value as a row.

Without using OPENJSON, how can I extract all the values within a array?

Comment: 100 is SQL Server 2008 mode. I really suggest upgrading the compatibility by now, if I am honest, you should have had more than enough time to test a newer one by now, as presumably you migrated off of SQL Server 2008 many years ago.

Comment: And you can always just stuff some generic `OPENJSON()` in a table-valued function in a database that isn't stuck in a depressing time warp. Can you show some sample data and desired results?